# Deletion of bulk records using spring jdbc

Tags: java, maven, spring-jdbc

I have two tables table1 and table2 and joining them using inner join on one column.
There is a possibility that child table can have more than 50 million recorrds.
It took 30 mins to delete 17 million records using spring jdbc update().
is there a optimized way  to reduce deletion time.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use **batchUpdate** with some copeable batch size, eg. 5000.</strike>

*EDIT:* The problem is probably not in Spring jdbc but in your query.

Would this work for you?

```
DELETE 
    res
FROM
    RESULT res
INNER JOIN
    POSITION pos
    ON res.POSITION_ID = pos.POSITION_ID
WHERE
    pos.AS_OF_DATE = '2012-11-29 11:11:11'
```

This removes entries from RESULT table. Simplified SQL fiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a71e/15

Comment: this.getJdbcTemplate().update(DELETE_RESULT_QUERY, asOfDate);

Comment: DELETE FROM RESULT WHERE RESULT_ID IN" +
            " (SELECT RESULT_ID FROM RESULT AS RESULT INNER JOIN DBO.POSITION AS POSITION ON" +
            " RESULT.POSITION_ID=POSITION.POSITION_ID " +
            " WHERE POSITION.AS_OF_DATE < ?

Comment: What RDBMS (mysql, mssql, oracle, etc.)?

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion and it has reduced couple of mins.

Comment: Very nice to hear! Consider accepting the answer (increases yours and mine reputation and marks this answer as sort of "case closed").